# xcode 7 Swift no longer generating template code when creating a new subclass file

Tags: swift, xcode7

I'm not sure what changed in my xcode 7 environment (I'm new to iOS dev), but when I create a subclass of something like UITableViewController, it use to generate a file with some of the common overrides as well as putting in an import of UIKit. Now when I generate a subclass, there's no overrides and the import is Foundation. Does anyone know how I can reset it back to the way it was?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Did you choose "Cocoa Touch Class" in the *iOS* template section?

Comment: Yes, and it does the auto-complete when I start typing UIView... so I don't know what's going on. It's frustrating because I'm just learning and having the template code made it easy to see what some of the more important overrides I might need.

Comment: Yes, make sure you're creating an iOS subclass and not an OS X or Swift file.

Comment: Yes, I'm subclassing UIKit classes for cocoa touch. There is an update to xcode (7.2) that I'm installing now. I'm not sure if that will fix the problem, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading xcode to version 7.2 (7C68) fixed the problem!